# oracle consume adapter service mapping error with multiple rows in flat file

Tags: oracle, biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I have a flat file with multiple rows. I just need to insert data from flat file to oracle db. I have manage to do that whit ONE row on my flat file but when there's more rows, I start to get errors from MAPPING TEST:

> ...has invalid child element 'xxx' in namespace...
>
> ...List of possible elements expected...

And if I deploy my project, the same thing. With one row in flat file everything works but with multiple rows not.

I have been using visual studio 2013 -> biztalk project -> FlatFileWizard and ConsumeAdapterService(INSERT), mapping and receive pipeline items.

I think it might be something to do with mapping properties and/or selecting xx.OracleDBBinding_xxxx schema...

Any ideas?

UPDATE

Mapping:

Flat File Record -> multiple Element Fields

OracleBinding -> insert(record), RECORDSET(record), RECORDINSERT(record), multiple records(each one with Attribute Field)

Is it even possible to MAP these?

Comment: You have not given us enough details to help you, please give more details

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering. I found a solution, which was very simple. Just needed to connect [map] (also) FlatFile Record to RECORDINSERT(record) at the high level. After that mapping all the wanted multiple Element Fields (FlatFile) to Multiple Records (OracleBinding).
Found the hint here: http://synthesisconsulting.net/blog/2012/5/10/oracle-and-biztalk-server-part-1.html